# What is the correct form of this piece?

Tags: musical-forms

In Schumann’s [“Of Foreign Lands and Foreign People“](https://musescore.com/user/10477211/scores/2980256), the sample test paper I have refers to it in **ternary form**. However, I can only see two distinct parts of the music (both of which are repeated).

Is this piece in ternary form and if so where are the A-B-C parts?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ternary form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_form) has two distinct sections, not three. In the simplest form that's A-B-A. The Schumann piece is a variation on that: A-A-B-A-B-A

Answer (score 4):

*Ternary form* does only mean 3 parts. This can mean any combination:

- AAA
- AAB
- ABB
- ABA
- ABC

(potentially with variations on repeats). Hereby the most common form is the form ABA. Now, this Schumann piece is of the form

|: A :||: B A :|

so it is essentially ABA with reapeats, or AABABA (note that AABA can also be seen as typical reprise form). Also the macroform AABB is a very typical binary form.